# How to call Ajax in wordpress in custom.php page?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a little weird problem

I want to call wordpress ajax url in a custom page.php in public_html

The weird thing is that I have two type of these pages which have two different path :

> First one is : the_permalink()/page1
>
> Second one is : the_permalink()/page1/page2

The problem is that the ajax url call is working fine in page1 path : the_permalink()/page1

But same functions with same way of calling is not working in page2 path : the_permalink()/page1/page2

Is there any suggestions ?

Note : i have tested the the SCRIPT code which call the ajax with alert() function and found that that the code stops when it becomes to ajax part is this code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.checknow').click(function(e){
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = "test";
        //alert(ajaxurl);
                
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action:'action_function_php', 
                data:data,
                },
            success:function(data){
                $('.security-check-result').html(data);
            }
        });

      });
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Note : i am using wildcard *, so the permalink return is subdomain if this would help

I have also tried to type the url directly but didn't work also

> Here is an example page ( will remove it soon ) - just for make things
> clear -

https://gameloop.bramj.store/windows

in this page if u tried to search something in the search bar you will find the ajax return works fine

but if you move to

https://gameloop.bramj.store/windows/download

you will notice that every single ajax code in the page is not working.

Comment: Do you have an error in the browser console? or only does not set the html?

Comment: no errors are shown as i think, i have included the example up there if you have time :), and thanks for your help

Comment: and after reviewing the console, yes an error is shown

Comment: problem is solved thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much the problem is solved

i had to put the current main url ( domain/ subdomain ) without any slugs

so the best solution for this case is use this url :

```
var ajaxurl = "https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_localize_script` in order to have access to `ajaxurl` global.
If you don't want to do that then you can replace ajaxurl with  `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>` if you javascript is inside a PHP file.

Comment: thank you for your reply my friend, but i tried this also and still not working, i have included an example up there if you are in, thanks again for your time and your help <3